# I have a data set that having profit column with negative values. what should I do?

Tags: data, powerbi

I am working on a data set that data set have a profit column with negative values what should I do can we remove it or ignore it .

Comment: Hi @akshaygaikwad. You should first understand why those negative values are there and then decide what makes sense to do with them from a business point of view depending on what you want to do with the data.